# 2.79 Multiple displace mods with different uv-maps and textures

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers, displacement

I have a model of a glass. I want to create three different displacements:

- one along the rim
- one in the middle
- one at the bottom.

I nearly succeeded there - I assigned a new material to, say, the bottom part, unwrapped that portion in the uv-editor, chose the corresponding uv-map, opened the correct uv-image.
After this, still having my relevant faces selected, I created a displace mod (called "GlasBoden"), chose the appropiate texture ("boden_glasrand"), chose "uv-map" and the respective map: "GlasBoden".

It worked!

I then repeated this for the middle part and the rim. But it seems I did do something different, because in the middle part there's not just ONE displacement, but two of them. If I disable my (correct) displacement "GlasMitte", I can also see the rim displacement applied to the faces I  had unwrapped in the "GlasMitte"-uv-map.

I've since then unset the rim and middle part in the uv-editor (twice, actually), re-assigned the textures, re-selected the uv-maps... still no success.

I feel I'm missing something in the creation of the uv-map. Maybe someone could explain what I did wrong? (I'd upload my file, but I'm not sure how to do this...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After looking around I found my answer, but for anybody having the same problem:
it seems the maps "inherit" islands and textures from the previous map. I got it to work with choosing my maps, resetting (Unwrap - reset) the islands and starting over.
I guess the best way would be to create all the maps you need prior to unwrapping any faces to make sure you don't have any unwanted "leftovers".